# How to convert T-SQL NOT IN Query into KQL and limit batch size with parameter in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am currently working on `ADX` and need to convert following `SQL` query into `KQL`

```
SELECT UserId, Column2, Column3 from Table1 t
where t.UserId NOT IN (Select UserId from Table2)
and t.Type = 'Something'
```

I also need to limit the result set with some configurable batch size parameter that would be pass from `.net core` `function app` using following code in `C#` so that it's not returning billions of records to application

```
        using (var queryProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder))
        {
            var query = "Table1  | count";

            using (var reader = queryProvider.ExecuteQuery(Database, query,null))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   // Console.WriteLine(reader);
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is stopping you? [KQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kql-quick-reference) is decently documented and you probably have the portal to try out your attempts to get to the correct query. You may also want to read through [KQL Query best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices)

Comment: Then you should do some research. SO's QnA Format is not the correct format for Tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started with SQL to KQL translation you can use the "explain" command, see more [here](https://SELECT%20UserId,%20Column2,%20Column3%20from%20Table1%20t%20where%20t.UserId%20NOT%20IN%20(Select%20UserId%20from%20Table2)%20and%20t.Type%20=%20%27Something%27)

As for passing the size parameter, you can append to the query text in the code `"| take X"` (where X is the number of records), or you can use [query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/queryparametersstatement?pivots=azuredataexplorer).

Comment: That's such a great response. I have got my query what I was looking for using explain. Thank you so much